# iOS 7.1 UINavigationBar backgroundImage behaviour

Tags: ios, ios7, ios7.1

Is there any specific documentation for `UINavigationBar` backgroundImage for iOS 7.1? Becuase  it behave differently with iOS 7.

What I want to achieve and already achieved on iOS 7.

[image: What I want to achieve]

This is achieved by putting UIImage on `UINavigatioinBar` using `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:img forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];`

But when on iOS 7.1, it changed to this screenshoot

[image: Appearance on iOS 7.1]

iOS < 7 and iOS 7 positioning is works properly using delta. but on iOS 7, it changed and the UI is broken. Because on iOS 7.1, UINavigationBar seems to be opaque when I set the backgroundImage. How to make UINavigationBar to become translucent like in iOS 7? so I don't need more position adjustment for each iOS version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

Comment: LOL. Damn. How I become so foolish. I even write the clue on my question about my problem. Thanks for point it out to me :)

Answer (score 1):

self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES; 
Must work